# Restore fragment state after ActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

I'm working on a fragment which displays a list of images. It has a button for "add image" that starts an intent for result with these values.

```
type: "image/*"
action: Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
```

The problem is: after the user picks an image and returns to the fragment, all the other images in the list (stored in some ArrayList<> on the code) are gone.

I've overridden the method `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` and saved the list inside the bundle. The thing is, there's no way to restore it back.

I thought of overriding `onViewStateRestored(Bundle)` but it didn't work. When I put some `Log.d()` on all "onXXX" methods, I found that only these three are executed every time I add a file (actual order):

```
onPause()
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)
//now the image picker opens up
//user picks the image
onResume()
//image picker closes and fragment is now on screen
```

I thought of using some "getXXX" method at `onResume()` but I can't find one that's useful. What can I do?

**EDIT:** Here is my code (without irrelevant stuff).

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("debugaff", "oncreate");
    setRetainInstance(true);
    this.attachments = (ArrayList<Attachment>) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(ExtraKeys.ATTACHMENTS);
}

@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Log.d("debugaff", "oncreateview");
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attachments_form, container, false);

    //....

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    } else {
        attachmentsRvAdapter.setItems((List<Attachment>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(ExtraKeys.TEMP_ATTACHMENTS));
    }

    //....

    return rootView;
}

@Override public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("debugaff", "onresume");
    hideKeyboard();
}

@Override public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    setRetainInstance(true); //called this to make it 100% redundant (already called it at onCreate)
    Log.d("debugaff", "onpause");
}

@Override public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Log.d("debugaff", "onviewstaterestored");
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    } else {
        attachments.addAll((List<Attachment>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(ExtraKeys.TEMP_ATTACHMENTS));
        attachmentsRvAdapter.setItems(attachments);
    }

    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: How do you receive the bundle back that you've saved using onSaveInstanceState()?

Comment: @zain Exactly, that's my question

Comment: have you tried  to override onActivityCreated()?

Comment: How is your fragment being added to your activity? I suspect that you're accidentally replacing your fragment with a new instance of the same class, rather than re-using the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I have just mimic your situation and found no error (list saves the new value with old values in the list). The only problem I can think of is you are not initializing your list correctly. What I did was to initialized the list in the onCreate() method and when I pick another Image it saves that image in the same list with the previous image still in the list. **There is no need to save the list separately in the savedInstanceBundle.** Here is my Fragment code:

```
public class SelectListFragment extends Fragment {


private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 11;

public SelectListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

List listOfImagesSelected;
Button selectButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listOfImagesSelected=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select_list, container, false);

    selectButton = view.findViewById(R.id.selectButton);
    selectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
    });
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    //I am retrieving the Bitmap from the intent and saving into the list 
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            //making the bitmap from the link of the file selected
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
            listOfImagesSelected.add(bitmap);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

    }
}
}
```

I can share the Complete Working Code of my Project if needed. For better understanding of the Fragment LifeCycle please review this Image

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To use `onViewStateRestored`, you need to call 'setRetainInstance(true);'

Comment: I found that somewhere and tried. Not really worked. Maybe it works for other types of restore, like from when the fragment fully closes or something...